# How to handle coordinates accuracy in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, coordinates, precision

I am creating very basic rectangular polygon using very basic a Python code

```
nCols,nRows=100,100
corners =[[0,0],[0,nRows],[nCols,nRows],[nCols,0],[0,0]]
p=arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in corners]))
arcpy.AddMessage(p.area)
```

and this is a message

10000.0244140774

It seems that forced conversion to doubles is a reason, as described in
[ArcGIS 10 exports losing precision with large numbers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9654/arcgis-10-exports-losing-precision-with-large-numbers/9657#9657)

Who can please tell how to get more accurate result?

P.S. Polygon created in ArcView 3 using same coordinates has an area of 10000.0000

**This is update on my original question**. Slightly modified code:

```
nCols,nRows= 101, 101
corners =[[1,1],[1,nRows],[nCols,nRows],[nCols,1],[1,1]]
p=[arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(*coords)) for coords in corners]
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(p, "d:/rubbish/points.shp")
p=arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in corners]))
arcpy.AddMessage(p.area)
```

produced correct answer(!). Area of polygon = 10000.

This is a relief, I don't have to write my own procedure in GIS to calculate area of the shape. What I don't like are coordinates of the points that makes this polygon:

[image]

Comment: Doubles (and floats) are imprecise by their nature. Learn to deal with a very small (some would say insignificant) difference and round it out. If you are expecting to get whole numbers then return *int(p.area)*, if you're expecting small numbers then round to a few decimals. The difference is 0.000244140774% of the total area in this case.

Comment: This may be a coordinate reference issue.  What is your default coordinate reference? What is the xy scale of the data frame?  There's nothing "forced" about double precision conversion -- that is the correct datatype for coordinate data.

Comment: @Vince this virtual shape, raster extent expressed in terms of column and row number. no coordinate system

Comment: @Michael, imprecision of floats is exactly the reason of what i am doing here. Have a look, i am dealing with integers. Since 2nd year at school i thought 100 times hundred is 10 thousands. Old arcview knows it also

Comment: You are putting them in as integers but they're stored internally as doubles... The Esri Geometry has to accommodate many different storage systems and has multiple co-classes and interfaces; a compromise has to be made somewhere. In the end no matter how big (wide) you make a floating point it's not going to store all numbers with 100% precision. If you want to calculate the area accurately you'll need to write and implement your own area calculation algorithm or round to an appropriate number of significant digits. It's not that 100 can't be stored as a double, it's the area calculation..

Comment: @FelixIP **Every** shape has a coordinate reference. This is intrinsic to ArcGIS.  Failure to set a *proper* coordinate reference (which is much more than a coordinate system) is causing your **precision** (not *accuracy*) issue.

Comment: @Vince i take it now work can be done in virtual world with origin in meters (0,0). Why help does it, e.g. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Polygon/018z00000061000000/

Comment: I just replicated this in ArcMap 10.3.1. I added a fc with unknown coordsys. xy domain starts at -450359962737.05,-450359962737.05. xy resolution is 0.0001. The '100' value is stored as 100.00012207.

Comment: @mkennedy Exactly. Square it and you'll get the value that bothers me. I just tried to modify script posted http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136715/how-to-get-cell-value-along-flow-direction/136954#136954 to make it look better (by replacing multiple IFs with intersect method) and hit the wall. Yes, I can live with it and still cannot understand why old ArcView does it and ArcGIS does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This observation goes back to 2010.  If a spatial reference isn't specified, then you will get lower precision results.
See https://geonet.esri.com/thread/10256 for starters.  The examples are more extensive.  There are even more in subsequent years.  Specifying a floating point input has no impact, so rule that out as a thought.

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> corners =[[0.0,0.0],[0.0,1.0],[1.0,1.0],[1.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0]]
>>> p=arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in corners]))
>>> p.area
1.0002441555261612
>>> # hmmmm close... try again
>>> SR = arcpy.SpatialReference(3395) # WGS_1984_ World_Mercator_3395.prj doesn't really matter
>>> p=arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in corners]),SR)
>>> p.area
1.0
```

How about pure Python? (very simple example obviously)

```
def polygon_area(pnts):  
  '''determine the area given a list of points'''  
  area = 0.0;  n = len(pnts)  
  j = n - 1;  i = 0  
  for point in pnts:  
    p0 = pnts[i];  p1 = pnts[j]  
    area += p0[0] * p1[1]  
    area -= p0[1] * p1[0]  
    j = i; i += 1  
  area /= 2.0  
  return area 

if __name__=='__main__':
  square = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]]  
  print('Unit square area: {}'.format(polygon_area(square)))
```

result...

```
>>> Unit square area: 1.0
```

Comment: Tick, though you answered it already. Although calculating area in GIS using subroutine is way over the top.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates get converted to doubles when the arcpy `Polygon` object is created and without a proper coordinate reference system, ArcGIS does not know how precise the result should be. If you use an appropriate coordinate system, the error is likely to diminish; however, it will never disappear due to limited double format precision.

Besides (not knowing everything about your use case), using rows and columns of an input raster as the reference system is suspicious at least. I'd suggest either using an alternative tool for whatever you're trying to accomplish with the non-geocoded image (such as the Python Imaging Library, MATLAB Image Processing toolbox or any raster-based GIS) or geocoding the image first and then performing the action such as clipping.

Comment: This suspicious thing called translation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry). Very convenient approach when working with rasters. e.g. cell value of 2 in flow direction raster http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000063000000.htm means that next cell is 1 row down and 1 column left