# arcpy handling of floating points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, floating-point

This arises from my own question [How to handle coordinates accuracy in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138956/how-to-handle-coordinates-accuracy-in-arcgis) where I have tried to use the documentation entitled [Using geometry objects with geoprocessing tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_geometry_objects_with_geoprocessing_tools/002z0000001z000000/) as a reference.

I have a table with coordinates in degrees:

[image]

I created event table and added it to the view with coordinates system 'GCS_NZGD_2000
WKID: 4167 Authority: EPSG'. I converted this single point to shapefile, defined it projection and computed coordinates of the point using 'Add Geometry Attributes' tool. This is resulting table with numbers as expected:

[image]

To replicate this in arcpy I've used this code:

```
corners =[[174.73,-36.76]]
p=[arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(*coords)) for coords in corners]
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(p, "d:/rubbish/points.shp")
```

I added output 'points.shp' to the view, defined projection and computed coordinates of the point using 'Add Geometry Attributes' tool. This is resulting table:

[image]

As one can see from the picture below the distance between 2 supposedly identical points is close to 10 meters:

[image]

However when I updated existing dataset **with defined projection** using

```
infc =r'd:\scratch\from_xy.shp'
outRows = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(infc,("SHAPE@","X"))
feat = (arcpy.Point(174.73,-36.76),0)
outRows.insertRow(feat)
```

It worked. Lessons:

1. Don't use examples similar to the documentation entitled [Using geometry objects with geoprocessing tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_geometry_objects_with_geoprocessing_tools/002z0000001z000000/)
2. Define projection of dataset prior to any games with geometries.

**Does the documentation entitled [Using geometry objects with geoprocessing tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_geometry_objects_with_geoprocessing_tools/002z0000001z000000/) need to be revised?**

Comment: Are you sure that there's not more decimals in the table? Did you enter those with exactly 2 decimal places? If this is true then it's *most troubling*, I frequently do XY Event layer > shapefile (I'm doing one at the moment with ~10 million points) in GDA94/MGA Zone 55... 3rd decimal doesn't mean much, but still, the geometries should be *exactly* where I place them within the limits of IEEE 754 Double Precision Floating Point. Is anyone else experiencing the same phenomenon?

Comment: Numbers shown as typed. The thing is, it is working perfectly fine with XY event added as table to frame with known coordinates. It is arcpy causing trouble

Comment: It's blowing my mind! This is *fundamental* and should just work; perhaps the NZGD has some sort of domain/precision/offset which rounds or offsets the coordinates.. but it shouldn't affect it unless you're calculating the geometry in a different spatial reference. Nicely picked up FelixIP! Thx for the warning.

Comment: So that this can be a question rather than a statement, and become answerable (which is the aim of SE), perhaps you can structure it along the lines of "Should the documentation at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_geometry_objects_with_geoprocessing_tools/002z0000001z000000/ be fixed?

Comment: @PolyGeo Could you please help me with this modification by editing original?

Comment: Done - hope it has not altered your meaning/intent.

Comment: Use a spatial reference object, which I think pointgeometry supports, check the help.  If a defined coordinate system is not used single precision is used in the calculations.  References to this phenomenon are documented on this site and on geonet and a comment isn't the place to put them.  No SR... = ... inaccurate results

Comment: @DanPatterson yes PointGeometry supports spatial reference. Finally an answer. Do you mind please post your comment as an answer?

Comment: If no SR (coordinate system), a default SR (xy/z/m domain, resolution, tolerance) is created based on a *projected* CRS. So resolution is 0.0001, tolerance is 0.001. This is wildly inappropriate for lat/lon data as in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested ... posting my comment here

Use a spatial reference object, which I think pointgeometry supports, check the help. If a defined coordinate system is not used single precision is used in the calculations. References to this phenomenon are documented on this site and on geonet and a comment isn't the place to put them. No SR... = ... inaccurate results –  Dan Patterson 33 mins ago