# Connecting every point with each other with line in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a dataset of points and I would like to make lines connecting each point with all the other points of the dataset.

It is similar to [Creating all possible line segments between all points using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366235/creating-all-possible-line-segments-between-all-points) but I want to do it in ArcMap.

Is this possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. What have you tried, and what problem did you encounter?

Comment: About 200 points. So basically the question is if there is already such tool available in ArcMap. Otherwise I can spend more time to do it manually with ArcPy (I guess by using multiple times the POINTS TO LINE tool)

Answer (score 7):

I dont know of such a tool.

You can use arcpy with [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import arcpy
from itertools import combinations
   
pointfc = r'C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb\samplepoints'
coordinates = [xy[0] for xy in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pointfc,'SHAPE@XY')] #List all point coordinates

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path='in_memory', out_name='lines', geometry_type='POLYLINE', spatial_reference=pointfc)
icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(r'in_memory\lines','SHAPE@')

sr = arcpy.Describe(pointfc).spatialReference
for p1, p2 in combinations(coordinates, 2):
    newline = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*p1), arcpy.Point(*p2)]), sr)
    icur.insertRow([newline])
del(icur)
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, learned something, thanks:  [itertools > combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: Always set a SpatialReference in the Polyline constructor, or the coordinates may have truncated precision.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138956/how-to-handle-coordinates-accuracy-in-arcgis